# pip install rpy2==3.2.7 error with code 1

Tags: python, pip, rpy2

Please anyone help me, i got these when ***pip install rpy2==3.2.7*** :

Collecting wheel
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/23/848298cccf8e40f5bbb59009b32848a4c38f4e7f3364297ab3c3e2e2cd14/wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel-0.34.2

(venv) C:\Users\billpebert\PycharmProjects\KlasifikasiKualitasUdaraC50>pip install rpy2==3.2.7
Collecting rpy2==3.2.7
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/c0/61120f9dae06b4887426d229b68a7a5f0ca1f9cb3986319bb9484819a28d/rpy2-3.2.7.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\billpebert\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-4l7yazyi\cffi\
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\billpebert\PycharmProjects\KlasifikasiKualitasUdaraC50\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\billpebert\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\Users\billpebert\PycharmProjects\KlasifikasiKualitasUdaraC50\venv\Scripts\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-versio
n-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\Users\BILLPE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvdyfy70j', '--quiet', 'cffi>=1.13.1']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\billpebert\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-22ktwibt\rpy2\setup.py", line 147, in <module>
    setup(
  File "C:\Users\billpebert\PycharmProjects\KlasifikasiKualitasUdaraC50\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 143, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "C:\Users\billpebert\PycharmProjects\KlasifikasiKualitasUdaraC50\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 138, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
  File "C:\Users\billpebert\PycharmProjects\KlasifikasiKualitasUdaraC50\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 695, in fetch_build_eggs
    resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\billpebert\PycharmProjects\KlasifikasiKualitasUdaraC50\venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 781, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
  File "C:\Users\billpebert\PycharmProjects\KlasifikasiKualitasUdaraC50\venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1066, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "C:\Users\billpebert\PycharmProjects\KlasifikasiKualitasUdaraC50\venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1078, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "C:\Users\billpebert\PycharmProjects\KlasifikasiKualitasUdaraC50\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 754, in fetch_build_egg
    return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
  File "C:\Users\billpebert\PycharmProjects\KlasifikasiKualitasUdaraC50\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
    raise DistutilsError(str(e))
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['C:\\Users\\billpebert\\PycharmProjects\\KlasifikasiKualitasUdaraC50\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-vers
```

ion-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\Users\BILLPE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvdyfy70j', '--quiet', 'cffi>=1.13.1']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\billpebert\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-22ktwibt\rpy2\

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow , please see this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://rpy2.github.io/:  "Installing should be as easy as `pip install rpy2` **except on Windows**."

Comment: @phd : this changed recently. Thanks for cffi's ABI mode and effort from Windows contributors  ` pip install` should now also work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Fixes for Windows only appeared with rpy2-3.3.2. If you `pip install rpy2` you will get the latest release (currrently 3.3.3).